# How to delete selected items from listview in android clicking on delete context menu item?

Tags: android

I want to create a multiple-choice listview; associate the listview to a contextual menu. The menu has a delete item. When I choose the delete item on the menu, the selected items in the listview must be deleted; of course the listview will appear without the deleted items, but I have problem when selecting delete item. This is my code

```
    String[] mycolors;
ListView myLis;
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myLis = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.colorList);
    mycolors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors_array);

    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, mycolors);

    myLis.setChoiceMode(2);
    myLis.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    myLis.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void CreateMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem mnu1 = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Delete");
    MenuItem mnu2 = menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Item 2");

}

private boolean MenuChoice(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 0:
        deleteSelectedItems();
        return true;
    case 1:
        Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Item 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        return true;

    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);
    CreateMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return MenuChoice(item);

}

public void deleteSelectedItems(){
    SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = new SparseBooleanArray();
    checkedItemPositions.clear();
    checkedItemPositions = myLis.getCheckedItemPositions();
    int itemCount = checkedItemPositions.size();

    for(int i=itemCount-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(checkedItemPositions.get(i)){
            Object toRemove = dataAdapter.getItem(i);
            dataAdapter.remove((String)toRemove);
        }
    }
    checkedItemPositions.clear();
    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: what is the crash log saying, and also you have an issue while clicking on delete that you know but we don't so post your issue instead